# Visual Studio Code Red Hat, Execute an XSLT transformation from an XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, visual-studio-code, redhat

I'm want to know how to transform XML with XSLT and found Red Hat for Visual Studio Code.

I installed VSCode and the Extension XML for Red Hat and also the OpenJDK.
I've placed two files in a folder 'xml1.xml' and the stylesheet 'xslt.xml1'.
But how do I parsed it???

Comment: vscode-xml provides support for XML editing but not to see the result of the apply of xsl file to a XML file. Please create an issue for that and we will see if other people could be interested.

Answer (score 0):

There’s now a Visual Studio Code extension which focuses on editing XSLT 3.0 and running XSLT transforms. A custom task provider allows XSLT Transforms to be configured and invoked in the same way as a standard VSCode build task, the task has some custom properties, for example to set XSLT parameters.

The details on running XSLT tasks is documented [here](https://deltaxml.github.io/vscode-xslt-xpath/run-xslt.html). Note this does require an installed Saxon Processor also.

The extension itself is on the [VSCode Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath)

[image]